# Javascript AWS SDK S3 upload method with Body stream generating empty file

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, upload, stream

I'm trying to use the method **upload** from **s3** using a ReadableStream from the module `fs`.

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) says that a ReadableStream can be used at `Body`param:

> Body — (Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream) Object data.

Also the **upload** method description is:

> Uploads an arbitrarily sized buffer, blob, or stream, using intelligent concurrent handling of parts if the payload is large enough.

Also, here: [Upload pdf generated to AWS S3 using nodejs aws sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257185/upload-pdf-generated-to-aws-s3-using-nodejs-aws-sdk) the @shivendra says he can use a ReadableStream and it works.

This is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3')

const s3 = new S3()

const send = async () => {
  const rs = fs.createReadStream('/home/osman/Downloads/input.txt')
  rs.on('open', () => {
    console.log('OPEN')
  })
  rs.on('end', () => {
    console.log('END')
  })
  rs.on('close', () => {
    console.log('CLOSE')
  })
  rs.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log('DATA: ', chunk)
  })

  console.log('START UPLOAD')

  const response = await s3.upload({
    Bucket: 'test-bucket',
    Key: 'output.txt',
    Body: rs,
  }).promise()

  console.log('response:')
  console.log(response)
}

send().catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

It's getting this output:

```
START UPLOAD
OPEN
DATA: <Buffer 73 6f 6d 65 74 68 69 6e 67>
END
CLOSE
response:
{ ETag: '"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"',
  Location: 'https://test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/output.txt',
  key: 'output.txt',
  Key: 'output.txt',
  Bucket: 'test-bucket' }
```

The problem is that my file generated at S3 (output.txt) has 0 Bytes.

Someone know what am I doing wrong?

If I pass a buffer on `Body` it works.

```
Body: Buffer.alloc(8 * 1024 * 1024, 'something'),
```

But it's not what I want to do. I'd like to do this using a stream to generate a file and pipe a stream to S3 as long as I generate it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's an API interface issue using NodeJS `ReadableStreams`.
Just comment the code related to listen event `'data'`, solves the problem.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3')

const s3 = new S3()

const send = async () => {
  const rs = fs.createReadStream('/home/osman/Downloads/input.txt')
  rs.on('open', () => {
    console.log('OPEN')
  })
  rs.on('end', () => {
    console.log('END')
  })
  rs.on('close', () => {
    console.log('CLOSE')
  })
  // rs.on('data', (chunk) => {
  //   console.log('DATA: ', chunk)
  // })

  console.log('START UPLOAD')

  const response = await s3.upload({
    Bucket: 'test-bucket',
    Key: 'output.txt',
    Body: rs,
  }).promise()

  console.log('response:')
  console.log(response)
}

send().catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

Though it's an strange API, when we listen to `'data'` event, the `ReadableStream` starts the **flowing** mode (listening to an event changing publisher/EventEmitter state? Yes, very error prone...). For some reason the S3 need a **paused** `ReadableStream`. If whe put `rs.on('data'...)` after `await s3.upload(...)` it works. If we put `rs.pause()` after `rs.on('data'...)` and befote `await s3.upload(...)`, it works too.

Now, what does it happen? I don't know yet...

But the problem was solved, even it isn't completely explained.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if file `/home/osman/Downloads/input.txt` actually exists and accessible by node.js process
2. Consider to use [`putObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) method

Example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');

const s3 = new S3();

s3.putObject({
  Bucket: 'test-bucket',
  Key: 'output.txt',
  Body: fs.createReadStream('/home/osman/Downloads/input.txt'),
}, (err, response) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('response:')
  console.log(response)
});
```

Not sure how this will work with `async .. await`, better to make upload to AWS:S3 work first, then change the flow.

---

UPDATE:
Try to implement upload directly via [`ManagedUpload`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#constructor-property)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');

const s3 = new S3();

const upload = new S3.ManagedUpload({
  service: s3,
  params: {
    Bucket: 'test-bucket',
    Key: 'output.txt',
    Body: fs.createReadStream('/home/osman/Downloads/input.txt')
  }
});

upload.send((err, response) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('response:')
  console.log(response)
});
```

Comment: The file exists and is accessible. The line `DATA: <Buffer 73 6f 6d 65 74 68 69 6e 67>` says that it was read. `putObject` sends the data on once HTTP request, it doesn't stream it to S3. `async .. await` is not a problem here. Thank you!

Comment: @osmanpontes wouldn't argue on this, you're right. Have you tried code I've suggested changing `putObject` to `upload` method?

Comment: @osmanpontes anyways, I'm suggesting to try `putObject` in testing purpose

Comment: I tried this and it worked as expected. ;]. Do you have some more insight?

Comment: `.upload()` method was initially created for browser. This might be a reason for misbehavior, either it should work on node.js - we're always use `.putObject()` method. It has only one  recommendation - 5GB max file size. And I haven't found an evidence in SDK sources what file is sent as single HTTP request, [looks like `.putObject()` uses `.upload()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/05b12ab01a319643a6320879991f224d1fc93f0e/lib/services/s3.js#L989) as underlying code. I recommend to take a look on [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/search?p=1&q=putObject&type=&utf8=✓)

Comment: Where did you check `.upload` was created for browser? The problem with `.putObject` is that I need to generate files bigger than 5GB. I messed up my mind saying `.putObject` use one single request. The reason was that it doesn't fit to me, as you mentioned about max file size. It's a little strange that `.putObject` uses `.upload`, once the first has a 5GB as limit and [the other doesn't](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/05b12ab01a319643a6320879991f224d1fc93f0e/lib/services/s3.js#L998).

Comment: @osmanpontes sorry can't find info in the [changelog](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) earlier than 2.4.8. So, you may don't mind it was initially made for browser, as it anyways should work for node.js according to the documentation.
Try to implement upload directly via [`AWS.S3.ManagedUpload`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#constructor-property), see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I found the problem. It's very tricky. I'm gonna write the answer now.